# Insert into not working to move data from one table to new table

Tags: sqlite

So I have 1 table that I created a with new constraints and trying to move the data from the old table into the new one but it is not working, it does not give an error or anything.

I created old table with:

```
CREATE TABLE Elements (
    _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
    Element TEXT, 
    Symbol TEXT, 
    MW TEXT)
```

New Table created with:

```
CREATE TABLE "Element" (
    "_id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    "ElementName" TEXT,
    "Symbol" TEXT,
    "MW" REAL,
    UNIQUE("ElementName") ON CONFLICT ABORT,
    UNIQUE("Symbol") ON CONFLICT ABORT)
```

These are the statements to move the data over but they all did not insert anything:

```
INSERT INTO "Element" ("ElementName","Symbol","MW")
SELECT "Element", "Symbol","MW"
FROM "Elements"

INSERT INTO "Element"
SELECT * FROM "Elements"

INSERT INTO Element (ElementName,Symbol,MW)
SELECT Element,Symbol,CAST(MW AS REAL) FROM Elements

INSERT INTO Element (_id,ElementName,Symbol,MW)
SELECT NULL,Element,Symbol,MW
FROM Elements
```

I cannot figure it out. Can someone possible tell me what is wrong with my insert statements to move the data.  The biggest change was the constraints on the table.

Comment: Are you getting a `Error: column ... is not unique` error perhaps?

Comment: @muistooshort I am not getting any errors returned from execution.  And the table is still empty.

Comment: Are there duplicates in the source table? What happens if you leave the UNIQUEs out?

Comment: Just checking... Are there any rows in the old table? Could you have accidentally deleted them thinking you were clearing out the new table (names are very similar)

Comment: @muistooshort The table does not contain duplicates.  It only contains 118 rows and there are only 118 elements.  I inserted all the values by hand so I know there is no duplicates.  However, it inserts if the unique is off.

Comment: Can you duplicate your problem on http://sqlfiddle.com ?

Comment: @muistooshort sorry I thought I responded.  I already have an answer below, but I was trying to build a sqlfiddle but it did not like my autoincrement so it would not build the schema.   Thank you though

Answer (score 1):

I tried and this worked for me.

```
INSERT INTO Element SELECT * FROM Elements
```

just removed `""` from Element and Elements

Answer (score 1):

The problem was fixed by deleting the table and recreating it again without all the quotes in it.  I do not know if this is a bug in SQLite Database Browser or what.  I used the statements below and it ran fine:

```
CREATE TABLE Element (
    _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    ElementName TEXT,
    Symbol TEXT,
    MW REAL,
    UNIQUE(ElementName) ON CONFLICT ABORT,
    UNIQUE(Symbol) ON CONFLICT ABORT)

INSERT INTO Element SELECT * FROM Elements
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
INSERT INTO Element (ElementName, Symbol, MW)
SELECT o.Element, o.Symbol, o.MW
FROM Elements as o
```

If that fails, please compare these outputs:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Elements;
SELECT COUNT(Element) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Element FROM Elements);
SELECT COUNT(Symbol) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Symbol FROM Elements);
```